# Как подключиться к базе данных MySQL на c# через тунель?

Tags: c#, mysql

Есть база данных на бесплатном хостинге (использую именно базу... сам сайт забросил... Почему?... Ну долго рассказывать... выделенного IP нет и т.д.)
Но большинство хостингов предлагают работать с базой только в phpAdmine, а из внешней программы не достучаться...

Установил скрипт tunnel.php
программу настроил -
`devart mysql dbforge` -
работает.
Видео с инструкцией взял от сюда:
[MySQL PHP tunneling connection](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e-dcqouPheg).
Всё хорошо,
но...
Я хочу, чтоб точно так же подключалась моя программа на шарпе... Нигде не могу найти код...
Кто знает как подключиться таким образом, чтоб работало, как и при "обычном" соединении, напишите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Если тебя интересует программная реализация то можешь посмотреть следующее: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43438/Connect-C-to-MySQL

Comment: а ведь тупель это чистый httprequest - и что мешает отправлять запросы http-запросами, получать данные?

Answer (score 1):

Если есть возможность подключиться по SSH, то будет совсем просто. Обычный MySQL клиент программный будет работать. Требуется только настроить проброс портов (фича SSH). В случае с Putty:

```
putty.ssh user@host.ru -pw p@ssW0rd -L 3396:localhost:3306
```

коннектиться к бд через localhost:3396

Comment: упс. некропост.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, у вас не будет подключаться. Ведь часто во многих бесплатных хостингах запрещены входящие подключения. Т.е вы можете использовать БД в рамках сайта.

Скрипт, вы надеюсь нашли? Просто если не будет коннектиться - это проблема на хостинге(Т.е то, что я описал выше)